# OCaml list match pattern

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml

So I'm writing a simple method that sums up the first 3 or less ints in a list
but i'm confused about the match patterns.
I currently have

```
let sums l = match l with
    | [] -> 0
    | (h1::h2::h3::_) -> h1+h2+h3
    | [h1;h2;h3] -> h1+h2+h3
    | [h1;h2] -> h1+h2
    | [h1] -> h1
```

Does this cover all the cases?
also how come for 3 or more elements I cant write something like [h1;h2;h3;_]?
Sorry if these question seem too simple, I just started learning OCaml and I cant find anything like this online.

Comment: Ocaml will give you a very explicit warning if it thinks the patterns do not cover all cases.

Answer (score 5):

> Does this cover all the cases?

Yes, they cover all the cases, but I would write:

```
let sums l = match l with
  | [] -> 0
  | [h1] -> h1      
  | [h1; h2] -> h1+h2
  | h1 :: h2 :: h3 :: _ -> h1+h2+h3
```

Your `[h1; h2; h3]` is redundant since `h1 :: h2 :: h3 :: _` matches it (with wildcard being `[]`)

> also how come for 3 or more elements I cant write something like [h1;h2;h3;_]?

<del>well, you just can't. This syntax is not valid.</del>
Edit: sorry I went crazy. This syntax is valid but it matches a list of four elements without binding the last element, which is not something you want.

Comment: thanks, so it is always best to match cases with few elements first?

Comment: no. in this case, different orders yield same code.

Comment: Technically, the syntax `[h1; h2; h3; _]` is valid, it just matches a list of four elements instead of what @Oxtis wants.

Answer (score 0):

For summing the first three elements of a list, your approach seems quite reasonable. Now imagine you're asked to sum the first five. What about the first *twenty*?

Yes, you do cover all of the cases, but it's possible to think of this in terms of just *two* cases using recursion.

We know that if we want to sum the first zero elements of any list, we'll get `0`. Likewise, if we want to sum the first `n` numbers in an empty list, we'll get `0`. So the only time that doesn't yield `0` is a non-empty list when `n` is greater than zero.

In that case we add the first element to summing `n - 1` elements of the tail of the list. Applying the function recursively to the tail and decrementing `n` will converge our function on the base case which returns `0`.

```
# let rec sum_first_n n lst =
    match lst with
    | x::xs when n > 0 -> x + sum_first_n (n - 1) xs
    | _ -> 0;;
val sum_first_n : int -> int list -> int = <fun>
# sum_first_n 3 [7; 8; 9; 10];;
- : int = 24
```

```
sum_first_n 3 [7; 8; 9; 10]
7 + sum_first_n 2 [8; 9; 10]
7 + 8 + sum_first_n 1 [9; 10]
7 + 8 + 9 + sum_first_n 0 [10]
7 + 8 + 9 + 0
24
```

We could also use [sequences](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Seq.html) (since OCaml 4.07) to take the first `n` elements and then fold `+` over them.

```
# let sum_first_n n lst =
    lst 
    |> List.to_seq
    |> Seq.take n
    |> Seq.fold_left (+) 0;;
val sum_first_n : int -> int list -> int = <fun>
# sum_first_n 3 [7;8;9;10];;
- : int = 24
```